# Give a specific text only for outlook

Tags: email, text, outlook, signature, banner

I have created an email signature for out company. We're really happy about it but once clients open the signature in Outlook there are red crosses instead of the images. I read on the internet that you can't help it because the user has to accept the images.

But i have an other idea. I want to display a text like: " Can't see any images please accept the images". I want this text only shows up on Outlook e-mail clients. Can anybody help me out?

Thanks for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed the images into the signature instead of referring to external images.

Comment: But can't I make a special text only appears on outlook?

Comment: You can have conditional CSS - see http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/

Comment: Hi Dimitry thanks for this article! Does this only work for CSS or also for HTML?

Comment: As far as I know in HTML.